# Python assert that properties contains in a dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm writing an unit test in Python and basically I have a class with attributes and I want to ensure that those attributes contains in another object. For instance I have the following class:

```py
class TestingConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = True
    SECRET_KEY = ''
```

What I want to check is if those properties with their values contains in an instance of an object, something like:

```py
t = list(dict(TestingConfig.__dict__).keys())[1:-1] # remove __module__ and __doc__
self.assertIn(t, list(dict(app.config).keys()))
```

where `app.config` is the instance with the possible attributes.

Of course this does not work, but just wanted to give an idea.

**EDIT:**

I tried this, but it works only for the keys, I need to ensure the values are also included.

```
attrs = set(list(dict(TestingConfig.__dict__))[1:-1])

self.assertTrue(attrs.issubset(set(list(dict(app.config)))))
```

**EDIT:**

I got it! I hope this helps someone in the future.

```
attrs = set(sorted(TestingConfig.__dict__.items())[:-2])
i = set(dict(app.config).items())
self.assertTrue(attrs.issubset(i))
```

Comment: If you found a solution you should post an answer, not add it to the question.

Comment: And you may want to accept your answer ;)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen relax a little bit, u are only allowed to accept your own answer after 24 hours.

Comment: Ah, sorry - thanks for the reminder, I'm still too new here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my last edit, to assert properties of different objects:

```
env_config_attrs = set(sorted(TestingConfig.__dict__.items())[:-2])
app_config_attrs = set(dict(app.config).items())
self.assertTrue(env_config_attrs.issubset(app_config_attrs))
```

alternative usings **vars** instead of **__dict __**:

```
env_config_attrs = set(sorted(vars(TestingConfig).items())[:-2])
app_config_attrs = set(dict(app.config).items())

self.assertTrue(env_config_attrs.issubset(app_config_attrs))
```

**Note:** This kind of test I use to ensure that my configuration objects are properly initialized. This assertion above unit tests this:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

config = ProductionConfig

if app.config['ENV'] == 'development':
  config = DevelopmentConfig
elif app.config['ENV'] == 'testing':
  config = TestingConfig

app.config.from_object(config)
```